# Array PHP para Array JS

Tags: php, javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte array em PHP

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Funcionarios] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [nome] => Funcionario Teste
                [assistmed] => 10
                [assistodont] => 1
            )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Funcionarios] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [nome] => Paulo Teste 2
                [assistmed] => 2
                [assistodont] => 2
            )

    )
```

Preciso transformar ele em JS.

Tentei

```
js_arr = JSON.parse('<?php echo JSON_encode($funcionarios2);?>');
```

E gostaria de manuseá-lo com o js. Porém não consigo pegar os dados, tentei os seguintes comandos:

```
alert(js_arr.id[0]);
alert(js_arr[id][0]);
```

Qual a maneira correta?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54254/discussion-on-question-by-punisher07-array-php-para-array-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso a melhor coisa a fazer é usar um `console.log` somente na variável para descobrir como está vindo a estrutura, assim:

```
console.log(js_arr);
```

Após ele retornar a estrutura, observe atentamente para descobrir como chama-lo, você pode usar o [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) para facilitar a leitura.

```
[  
   {  
      "Funcionarios":{  
         "id":"3",
         "nome":"Funcionario Teste",
         "assistmed":"10",
         "assistodont":"1"
      }
   },
   {  
      "Funcionarios":‌​{  
         "id":"1",
         "nome":"Pa‌​ulo Teste 2",
         "assistmed":"2",
         "assistodont":"2"
      }
   },
   {  
      "Funcionarios":{  
         "id":"5",
         "nome":"Sem Med/Odont",
         "assistmed":"0",
         "assistodont":"0"
      }
   }
]
```

Dai agora fica fácil de descobrir como chegar ao campo que você quer:

```
var nomeFuncionario1 = js_arr[0]['Funcionarios'].nome
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.